# Конвертировать List в массив

Tags: java, массивы, список, конвертация

Здравствуйте,  как в Java  можно конвертировать Список числовых массивов, в массив массивов
(ArrayList int[] to int[][])?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `ArrayList` имеет метод `toArray`, который позволяет создать массив на основе элементов списка.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    static int [] make_array( int n )
    {
        int [] a = new int[n];

        for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) a[i] = i;

        return a;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ArrayList<int []> lst = new ArrayList<int[]>();

        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            lst.add( make_array( i + 1 ) );
        }

        int[][] a = new int[lst.size()][];

        lst.toArray( a );

        for ( int[] row : a )
        {
            for ( int x : row ) System.out.print( x + " " );
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль

```
0 
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Спасибо, вот такой код будет верным в моем случае?  
`ArrayList<int[]> x = new ArrayList<>();
 int[][] y = x.toArray(new int[x.size()][]);`

Comment: @Flappy Я дополнил свой ответ примером.:)